# Kinetic JS - getDragLayer version 4.4

Tags: kineticjs

I update Kinetic JS from 4.3.1 to version 4.4, I get the following error with getDragLayer:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'getDragLayer'
```

I am using the following script.

```
 stage.getDragLayer().afterDraw(function () {
                layer.draw();
            });
```

Complete project at http://jsfiddle.net/user373721/sTbFV/.  I would appreciate your suggestions, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you're right.

getDragLayer() is in version 4.3.3 and it's not in version 4.4.

I haven't digested the changes to the Kinetic 4.4 source code yet, but you can still use .afterDraw() on a layer.  This leads me to suggest that you could just do myLayer.afterDraw instead of stage.getDragLayer.afterDraw().  Don't quote me on that though...I haven't tried it!

Comment: Thanks Mark, unfortuantely it did not work, I didn't get any eror; and it worked on one stage perfect.  I am using two stages on the same screen; so if I move an object on one stage, it moves similar object on the second stage; the matter of fact you have helped with this issue.  The problem is I can't move any object on the second stage, it seems as if it locked.  I made a sample at http://jsfiddle.net/user373721/js3VU/6/.  Thanks for your help again.